# Multi-Variable Limit Problem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am having difficulty showing that the limit of 
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2+y^2\sin(x)}{x+y}$$ as (x,y) goes to (0,0). does not exist. All the usual tricks of computing the limit along $(0,x)$ and $(0,y)$ and $(x,mx)$ are giving me limits of $0$. Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Limit when x,y goes go (0,0)?

Comment: yes sorry I will edit

Comment: One way to look at it is to think about the fact that sin(x) acts like x near 0.

Comment: In the first place, $f(x,y)$ is not defined in a full neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yes, but still I think we can talk about a limit. For example the function $f(x)=1$ defined on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is $\Omega:={\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{(x,y)\>|\>x+y=0\}$, and the origin $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $\Omega$.  The curve
$$\gamma:\quad x\mapsto {\bf z}(x):=(x, \> -x+x^3)\in\Omega\qquad(0< x\leq1)$$
approaches the origin as $x\to0+$. If the $\lim_{{\bf z}\to{\bf 0}, \ {\bf z}\in\Omega} f({\bf z})$ would exist then the  $\lim_{x\to0+}f\bigl({\bf z}(x)\bigr)$ would exist as well. But
$$f\bigl({\bf z}(x)\bigr)={x^2+x^2(1-x^2)^2\sin x\over x^3}={1\over x}\bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)\qquad(x\to0+)$$
tends to $\infty$ as $x\to0+$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let us make the bottom "small" while the top stays "big."  Let $y=x^{10}-x$.